# Assign list to character with apply R?

Tags: r, apply, assign, sapply, mapply

I have a vector `x=c("a","b","c","d")` and `s` a list of 4 element as follow :

```
x [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

##and 

s
[[1]]
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6
  1   0   1   0   1   1 

[[2]]
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6 
  1   0   1   1   1   1 

[[3]]
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6 
  1   0   1   0   0   1 

[[4]]
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6
  1   0   1   0   1   0
```

By using **apply**, I want to get a **vector** of the assignment of each element of the list s to each x (I mean `assign(x[1],s[[1]])` and `assign(x[2],s[[2]])` ...

```
> assign(x[[1]],s[[1]])
> x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
> a
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6
  1   0   1   0   1   1 

> assign(x[[2]],s[[2]])
> b
 N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6 
  1   0   1   1   1   1 

 ...
```

Comment: Not clear...Are you looking for `setNames(your_list, x)`?

Answer (score 1):

We can assign `x` as `names` to `s` and then use `list2env` to get them as separate objects.

```
names(s) <- x
list2env(s, .GlobalEnv)
```